# JQuery .show() - no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked a couple of examples on here of using .show() but I still can't get mine to work.  My goal is to have div "gateInformation" pop up when the "gateNeededYes" radio button is pressed. So far the div stays hidden. If anyone could explain where I'm going wrong it would be very much appreciated!
Here is the code:
CSS:

```
#gateInformation {
    display: block;
}
```

JS:

/Gate Information

```
if($('#gateNeededYes').prop('checked')){
        $("#gateInformation").show("blind" , 1000);
    }
```

HTML:

Gates Needed:

```
            No <input type="radio" name="gateNeeded" id="gateNeededNo" />
            Yes <input type="radio" name="gateNeeded" id="gateNeededYes" />
            <div id="gateInformation" name="gateInformation">
                Gates Needed: 
                <select name="gateHeight" id="gateHeight">
                    <option value="select">Select Gate Height</option>
                    <option value="4fg">4 Ft. Gate</option>
                    <option value="6fg">6 Ft. Gate</option>
                    <option value="8fg">8 Ft. Gate</option>
                </select>
                Pool Spring and Latch: 
                <input type="checkbox" name="psl" id="psl">
            </div>
```

Comment: try setting `display: none;` I believe that should get it to work

Comment: What is executing that if statement? Your code should work, assuming it's in the change event of said radio buttons.

Comment: this is the issue... `$("#gateInformation").show("blind" , 1000);`... should be `$("#gateInformation").show(1000,"blind");`

Comment: @zgr024 No, the effect comes first. http://api.jqueryui.com/show/

Comment: @zgr024 - effect first, then speed

Comment: OK I was looking at http://api.jquery.com/show/ since the question is asking for jQuery .show(), not jQuery UI

Comment: The regular `show()` function doesn't have effects, jQuery UI is needed for that

Comment: @adeneo regular `show()` has easing... `.show( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to show something, it has to start out hidden

```
#gateInformation {
    display: none;
}
```

then you'll need an event handler

```
$('#gateNeededYes').on('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#gateInformation").show("blind", 1000);
    }
});
```

Then you'll have to include jQuery UI for effects to work with `show()`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/D5SYV/)

Comment: @Jean-Paul - The OP didn't ask for that, and if so that's not the way to do it, this is -> http://jsfiddle.net/D5SYV/1/

Comment: `toggle` is indeed better. Didn't ask but it's still a nice feature isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if you use old jQuery: in jQuery 1.5 and older you have to use `.attr('checked')` instead of `.prop('checked')`

**EDIT**:

jQuery 1.5, not 1.8

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the code once the radio button is pressed then you can try the `click` event too as:

```
$('#gateNeededYes').click(function () {
```

Comment: That is not right, `prop()` does not use `:checked`. I think you are confusing it with `is()`

Comment: @epascarello you're right, I was confusing it with the `is()` method..thanks for correction sir :)